# What is the English word for "something stupid done by a child", similar to French "faire une bêtise"?

Tags: translation, french

In French, we have the word **bêtise** that I find surprisingly hard to translate. Bêtise (coming from adjective *bête*, "dumb") has different meanings, all related to "dumbness": its first sense is "default of intelligence", akin to *nescience*.

One of these meanings is more often used in everyday life: **"faire une bêtise"**. Making a *bêtise* is making a childish mistake, like spilling a glass, breaking something, hurting someone and the like. When a child does something stupid, the child can go to parents and say "mom, I've made a *bêtise*".

How would you translate this in English?

"Mom, I've made *something stupid*" is the phrase that comes to my mind but I am not really satisfied because it does not carry the same context of childishness.

"Mom, I've made a *mistake*" does not really satisfy me either because a "bêtise" can be something that is not a mistake, something voluntary, planified, and without regrets.

"Mom, I've made a *folly*" is one that I found online, and to me it sounds quite good, but I fear it is not really commonly used by children.

What would a child say to his or her parents? How would you translate, in this context, "bêtise"?

As a footnote: bêtise is not only used by children. It can simply mean "mistake", or even be an euphemism for suicide, in addition to being a [sweet](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%AAtise_de_Cambrai). But I am more interested in an English equivalent in the context of childhood mistakes.

Comment: Possibly "boo-boo"?

Comment: or [mischief](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mischief) (*behaviour, especially a child's, that is slightly bad but is not intended to cause serious harm or damage*)

Comment: @Graffito Mischief is great! Thanks. Leaving the question a bit more to see if we get addtional answers.

Comment: I don't think "mischief" works here at all.  Mischief is bad behaviour, not foolish/stupid. I think "I've done something silly/stupid/foolish",  or "I've made a silly/stupid/foolish mistake" might work for the context you describe.  You have to be careful here.  Your 1st and 3rd examples are not idiomatic in English.  You don't **make** something stupid" . . . you **do** something stupid.  Also "folly" isn't used this way in English either. "to make/do a folly" is not really something a native speaker would say.

Comment: Google Translate translates _faire une bêtise_ as _to do something stupid_, which phrasing is perfectly reasonable - "Mom, I just did something stupid".

Comment: It's worth noting that _bête_ means _dumb_ in the American sense of 'stupid', not the British sense 'unable to speak'.

Comment: @BillyKerr: See [Googles images](https://www.google.com/search?q=kids+mischief&tbm=isch&source=univ&usg=AI4_-kT-uZAr7PL0pu8dVNsl5URj_7tTZg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-x_v9voSBAxXTTaQEHegyAf8QjJkEegQIFBAC&biw=1680&bih=869&dpr=1) corresponding to "kids mischief".

Comment: @Graffito - yes, precisely. Mischief is bad behaviour. However, you can't really use "I've done/made a mischief" either. It's not idiomatic. Native speakers do not say this.

Comment: @BillyKerr: True, but my proposal corresponds to the question in the title.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know that we have a single noun that’s equivalent, but you can certainly use a noun **phrase**. As @Jeff Zeitlin commented,

> Mom, I’ve done something stupid.

is 100% idiomatic. Or,

> Mom, I’ve made a dumb, childish mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, we often say a foolish mistake - the kind made due to inexperience - is "*a schoolboy error*". In US English, the equivalent is "*a rookie mistake*". But we say these about mistakes made by people of any age.

If you are actually speaking about 'inconsequential' mistakes that a child might make then you might consider "*[boo-boo](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boo-boo)*" (eg "*mum, I made a boo-boo*") to show it is a minor error. Many parents teach diminutive terms to their kids (such as "*ouchie*" for a mistake that leads to them hurting themselves) because it can help to diminish the upset from it. Other terms such as "*blunder*" or "*gaffe*" can also diminish the degree of mistake, but are not so much associated with children.

If you want to talk about a more serious mistake made by a literal child and show that it has only been made due to their youth and inexperience I'm not sure there are specific idioms, but we'd certainly understand if you said "*a childish mistake*".

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know boo-boo could be used in this context (I thought it was only for injuries).

Comment: @C.Crt That's right - Websters (chiefly US) and Cambridge (chiefly British) both list 'mistake' as definitions for this.

Answer (score 0):

The word **bêtise** does also exist in English, with roughly the same meaning. But I don't think it would be used by a child; I, an adult, was not even aware of its existence before researching this answer.

One thing to know about the word **mischief** is, it's always deliberate. I don't feel **mischief** describes your example of spilling a glass [of milk]. It could describe breaking something or hurting someone, but only as a deliberate action. **Mischief** could include putting sugar in someone's petrol tank, or yanking a schoolgirl's pigtail.

**Boo-boo** is a term that fits, I think. It sounds decidedly child-like, and could describe small mishaps like smashing a vase or spilling yoghurt on the carpet. But it can also describe deliberate, but regretted, actions such as stealing a bag of sweets or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think boo-boo works good.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a phrase that a child could say, this would work:

> Mom, I made an accident.
>
> Mom, I did something by accident.

"make an accident" is not perfectly idiomatic but is something a young child could well say to indicate that they've caused some harm unintentionally, such as knocking over a glass of milk or breaking something fragile.

Note to "to *have* an accident", when said by a child, could mean that they didn't make it to the toilet in time.